# Does this set of numbers contain infinitely many primes?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Define the set $A_a$ as $A_a=\{ \frac {a^n-1} {a-1} ; n\in \mathbb N \setminus\{1,2\} \}$. Now define the set $A$ as $A=\bigcup_{a=2}^\infty A_a$.

> Does $A$ contain infinitely many primes?

(It could be that this is trivial but I do not see some easy way to prove that there are or that there are not infinitely many primes in the set $A$.)

Comment: Related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repunit#Repunit_primes

Comment: It doesn't look like we know even this much about repunit primes, but Wikipedia doesn't quite assert that, it is just mum on it.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I was somehow, at least partially, aware that it is not known whether there are infinitely many primes in any single $A_a$ but I thought that the same question is maybe known if we take all $A_a$´s together as in above defined set $A$. Maybe some elementary enough way could be found for resolvement of the question I stated?